# How to get blob file name?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I've got a pl/sql procedure that returns Blob. This is how I call it:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;
Blob blob = null;
cstmt = con.prepareCall("{? = call billing.PREQUEST.GetAttachment(?)}");
                                cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,
                                        OracleTypes.BLOB);
cstmt.setInt(2, id);
cstmt.execute();
blob = cstmt.getBlob(1);
```

Now I want get a file name from blob. How can I do that?

Comment: What kind of file was saved?  Typically most files do not have a name embedded inside of them... Usually you would store the metadata alongside the binary bytes (things like filename, etc) in separate columns or tables

Answer (score 1):

A `BLOB` column does not store a file name. You need to add a separate column of type `VARCHAR2` for storing the original file name.

If your dealing with an existing database that already contains a lot of data, then you're out of luck. The file name was not stored and there is no way to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the `Blob` into a `File`. Try this code:

```
Blob blob = cstmt.getBlob(column);
InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("OutputFile");
byte[] buff = new byte[4096]; 
int length = 0;

while ((length = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
    out.write(buff, 0, length );
}

// From here, read in the File and just call "getName()"
// Also, make sure to call to close out and in
```

Comment: This would not provide the OP with the original filename that had been stored as a byte stream

Comment: I agree that the `File` column type might help. But I don't see what the provided code has to do with your answer.

Comment: I was providing a way to create a File and then just get the name from there. I didn't want to provide the whole solution.